# NuxtJs dynamic routing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dynamic, routes, nuxt.js

In NuxtJS (vuejs framework), I am having some difficulty with routes, I wanted to ask how we can create this kind of route using pages directory or any other approach?

**Example:**

Sample routes:

`/some-route-of-page-2021`

`/some-route-of-page-2022`  and so on for every year.

`2021`/`2021` is the year and that will be **dynamic**

Comment: I am migrating the old Laravel application and I need to keep the same route structure using Nuxt2. @kissu

Comment: I guess you will need to do it by hand. You could also have [an alias](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module), generate it programmatically and then have a "generic" page that will resolve the proper year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a dynamic variable **inside** of a path itself is supported [in Nuxt3](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/pages/#dynamic-routes) . In Nuxt2, you can only have [`/some-route-of-page/XXX`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing/#dynamic-routes). In this case, it seems a bit more logical to have this kind of structure anyway. Usually, you don't have a lot of variables interpolated in the path itself, can be kinda confusing IMO.